# Session timeout on different tab of browser in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

My problem is that:-
I have login page.After doing successful login with credentials redirect to home page. url:- http:localhost/test/home.aspx. That is fine.After doing this Once i copy the same url and paste on different tab in browser always open home page. That should not be. My requirement is that once the user copy the url http:localhost/test/home.aspx on different tab Session must be logout and Always redirect to login page.Anybody can be help me out?

Comment: This is strange requirement. Still go through IsPostBack page property, it might help.

Comment: This is a nonsense requirement that will require you to fight against the way browsers and sessions work. The session is shared between the browser and the server, not between individual tabs and the server. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: As yahoo works. If you copy yahoo url and paste on different tab. Always opening login page. That should be

Comment: Keep session id etc in url instead of cookie

Comment: Hello David, Must be session timeout once the user paste the url on different browser object. Session must be logout.

Comment: It's working fine on localhost.Not working on IIS once i deployed the site on IIS.

Comment: @anuj : u got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check if its postback, and if it is not then do a logout and redirect to login

Comment: IsPostBack _and_ is logged in _and_ referrer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[source](http://ASP.NET%20Session%20State%20Overview)

This will generate each tab a unique session ID.

Comment: This is a possibility, but really ugly, and you don't give any detail of the implications. It might be better to check the postback referrer is the login page.

Comment: I give the details source of this !! What more he want ?

Comment: Grant, After successfully login, open home page. During that time current session is running and page is not postback. in home page. there is link contactus page. once click on contactus page redirect to contact us page. Now the page is postback. Now i copy the url during this time session not expired. opening the another browser and paste the url opening contactus page. i want session must be expired automatically and redirect to login. Please help on this